# usageStatsManager.queryEvents does not fetch any event in Android 33

Tags: java, android

The below code is being used to fetch current top activity with a foreground service. The code work well for android API <= 32. But in android API 33 `myUsageEvents.hasNextEvent()` check always returns false, indicating the query did not find any event. So far, I have tried with emulator only, but I think it would be same in a real device as well. Because the code is working fine in emulator api 30 - 32.

The things checked / tried so far:

- Ensure app has runtime permission for `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`
- query for a longer during. i.e 24 hours

  ```
    public static String getTopPkgName(Context context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getTopPkgName: called!");

    String pkgName = null;

    UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long beginTime = endTime - 1000 * 60 * 5; // 5 minutes
    final UsageEvents myUsageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(beginTime, endTime);
    while (myUsageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
        UsageEvents.Event myEvent = new UsageEvents.Event();
        myUsageEvents.getNextEvent(myEvent);

        Log.d(TAG, "getTopPkgName: processing event for package: " + myEvent.getPackageName());

        // Some business logic to determine current top package. Below is a sample line
        pkgNamemyEvent.getPackageName();
    }
    return pkgName;
  ```

  }